# Iterating through each records Entity Framework Server side pagination

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, pagination

Iterate through all records via Pagination
There is one table with around 7650000 records and i want to iterate through all the records
to do some processing. I am using Entity Framework Query and using the concept of server side pagination
The query is looks like

```
        int totalBatches= 7650;
        int batchSize =1000;
        for (int i = 0; i <= totalBatches+1; i++)
        {
            int firstId = 0, lastDbId = 0;
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing  Batch {i.ToString()} of {totalBatches}");
            var batch = context.TableName
                                .Include(x => x.RelatedTable)
                                .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                            .Skip(i).Take(batchSize).ToList();
            if (batch.Count() <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"SKIPPING LOOP SINCE NO RECORDS EXISTS");
                break;
            }
            
            foreach (var entry in batch)
            {
            //processing each records
            }
        }
```

Looks like the execution is completed without any errors , but when i checked the summary of processed records there
are some mismatch on records. It took around 6+ hours for me to complete the execution of the script
The data base is Mysql and I am using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql driver as dependency

So wondering the pagination logic is correct or not
Is there any better way of doing server side pagination ? Or does this approach cause any loss of data ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways this approach is slow.

---

`Skip(a).Take(b)` is slow because it actually forces the DB to prepare `a + b` rows to send, then ignore `a` rows, which makes subsequent queries slower and slower, resulting in O(n^2) complexity. Unfortunately, for this DB operation to be O(n) you need a different way of paginating. This is very good reading on the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/pagination

---

*this is assuming you're using the default way of detecting changes, it applies if you haven't implemented `INotifyPropertyChanging`, `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your entities and made your DBContext not use snapshots*.

*This also assumes your code does this:*

1. start a transaction
2. get batch
3. process entities in batch
4. call `.SaveChanges()`
5. repeat 3. and 4. until you've gone through all entities
6. end transaction

By default, the `DBContext` has to keep track of all the entities it has given out to you (in your case via `.ToList()`). The `DBContext` unfortunately has no way of knowing when you're done making changes to any specific entity, therefore it has to keep track of **every single entity**.

Because of this, the internal set of those entities is only getting bigger, and each time you call SaveChanges() it has to check for changes on the entities in the current batch **as well as all the entities in all the previous batches**, resulting in O(n^2) complexity of checking for changes as well as O(n) memory complexity (!!)

To combat this, you could call `context.ChangeTracker.Clear();` after every `context.SaveChanges();` to effectively tell the context you're not going to be doing any changes to the entities in previous batch(es).

---

As a third option, if the entity processing itself is simple (like just adding some number to a column of all rows) and you're using quite recent version of EF you could try to use bulk updates which make the whole thing run on the DB. Read about `ExecuteUpdate` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew